# How can I use dll file from matlab in c++ project?

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, model, header

Hello everyone I had a problem I exported a model from matlab. the model outputs are .h and .dll and .lib files. I linked them to my c++ project. I have to use functions which are in my header. But in my header file my functions dont see the dll I guess.
My .lib file working correctly

these are my functions in .h file

```
extern void sineW_initialize(void);
extern void sineW_step(void);
extern void sineW_terminate(void);
```

the problem is function definition not found but in the dll already have func definition.
How can I use these functions?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and copy-paste the full error message into it. It is hard to know what the problem is from this description. Technical details matter!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't see an error message because the compiler is running but functions can't importing from dll. I solve the problem. I had 2 path for matlab first in c/programfiles/matlab than second is c/programfiles/polyspace after I added second path to my linker in vs the problem dissapear.